# How to send the state of a Text Input variable to a reducer with dispatch and display it on another screen?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I want the state of my variable (with which it is given a value from a textInput) is sent to a reducer and change the state of that reducer by the state of the variable that I sent, so that way I can show it in different screens using mapStateToProps and I get it globally.

Is there any way to do that? I researched and found examples but not the way I want to do it.

**I clarify my code is just an example so that you understand what I want to do, do not take it as a guide as I do not know if it works that way**

I show you some of my code to give you an idea of ​​what I

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
        View,
        Text,
        StyleSheet,
        TextInput,
        TouchableOpacity
    } from "react-native";

    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    class ScreenHome extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null
        }
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                Texto: '',
            }
        }

        render() {
            this.props.ChangeState({type: 'ACTION_TYPE', Texto: this.state.Texto});
            const { navigation } = this.props;
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                        value={this.state.Texto}
                        onChangeText={Texto => this.setState({ Texto })}
                    />
                    <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: 'black', padding: 10 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.ChangeState}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Send Text Input status to the reducer</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', padding: 10 }} onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Other') }}>
                            <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Go</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            // prop: state.prop
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
             ChangeState: () => {
            //     dispatch({ type: 'ACTION_TYPE', Texto: this.state.Texto });
             }
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScreenHome)

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }
    });
```

**OTHER SCREEN:**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ScreenOther extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }
    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.props.StateInitial}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Home') }}>
                    <Text>Go back</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        StateInitial: state.reducerText
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    //    ChangeState: () => {
    //          dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_TEXT'})
    //     }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScreenOther)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const reducerText = (state = [0], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ACTION_TYPE':
        return {...state, Texto:action.Texto};

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const Reducers = combineReducers({
    reducerText
})

const Store = createStore(Reducers)

export default Store;
```

Comment: What do your reducers and actions look like?

Comment: That is what I have not yet implemented because I do not know how to do it, my idea is to send a dispatch to reduce the state of my variable that in this case is "Text" and change the state of the reducer by "Text" so in the other screen I show it this way "<Text> {this.props.TEXT} </ Text>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who look at this post and want to do something similar, I mean send the status of the textInput variable to a reducer and ask for the status from another screen with redux feel free to see the code that I will leave below since I was investigating and I got it after a while.

This is the code of **redux-form**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    TextInput,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    Text
} from "react-native";

import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ScreenFormHome = (props) => (
    <View>
        <Field name="Text" component={fieldNombre} ph="Enter Text" />
        <Button title="Send Dispatch" onPress={props.handleSubmit((values) => props.SendDispatch(values))} />
    </View>
);

const fieldNombre = (props) => (

    <View style={styles.textInput}>
        <TextInput
            placeholder={props.ph}
            onChangeText={props.input.onChange}
            value={props.input.value}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            onBlur={props.input.onBlur}
        />
        <View style={styles.linea} />
    </View>

);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textInput: {
        marginBottom: 16,
    },
    linea: {
        backgroundColor: '#DCDCDC',
        height: 2,
    },
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        SendDispatch: (values) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'ACTION_TYPE', Text: values.Text })
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        //  StateInitial: state.reducerText
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'ScreenFormHome',
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ScreenFormHome));
```

**and this is the component code**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
        View,
        Text,
        StyleSheet,
        TouchableOpacity
    } from "react-native";

    import ScreenFormHome from "./ScreenFormHome";

    class ScreenHome extends Component {

        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null
        }

        render() {
            const { navigation } = this.props;
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', padding: 10, marginBottom: 10 }} onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Other') }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Go</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <ScreenFormHome />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }

    export default ScreenHome;

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }
    });
```

This is the **Store** code

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form'

const reducerText = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ACTION_TYPE':
            return (action.Text)
        default:
            return state;
    }
};


const Reducers = combineReducers({
    reducerText,
    form
})

const Store = createStore(Reducers)

export default Store;
```

Answer (score 0):

dispatch1 should be visible in your props in the homescreen. So if you do

`this.props.dispatch1({type: 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE', Text: this.state.Text});`

Your reducer function will be called where you can do:

```
reducer: (state, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE':
        return {...state, Text:action.Text};
     }
  }
```

Then in the other screen you should get the changed Text prop.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding is something similar to what I was testing even if the logic is correct the problem is that I throw this error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.state.Text'), I think it's poruqe enter the this.state also probe into putting something like this in "const {Text} = this.state;" but it did not work either

Comment: And this "this.props.dispatch 1 ({type: 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE', Text: this.state.Text});" I implemented it in the render but nothing happened :(